# OnePlus One - How to enable USB Debugging with broken TWRP

Tags: usb-debugging, twrp, oneplus-one

My device is Oneplus One, I installed Android 7.0 on it, then I installed OxygenOS 3.1.3. Then I thought to get back to CyanogenMod 13.0 with SultanXDA 3.4.0 kernel.

I've got bootloop, but I still don't know why.

I've noticed that my TWRP version was 3.0.3.2 (by Tugopower) so I wanted to reinstall it using the original TWRP recovery 3.0.2.0 image.

I installed TWRP successfully and pressed Reboot -> Recovery but after that I can't get access to TWRP anymore.

Fastboot says that USB Debugging is disabled.

How can I enable USB Debugging in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need debugging mode to flash. You must boot in bootloader (Fastboot mode) and flash the files.

This [tutorial](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/oneplus-one-gets-android-5-1-1-yog4pas1n0-cyanogen-os-12-1-ota-update-how-install-manually-1517108#) explains clearly the whole process. You need the second method since you are not able to boot in recovery mode.

[image]